# C# Delete all files in a listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I add some files to a listbox on a button:

```
if (Directory.Exists(DirString))
{
DirectoryInfo dirETC = new DirectoryInfo(DirString);
FileInfo[] Files = dirETC.GetFiles("*.txt");
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(file.FullName);
}
```

If user clicks the delete button, i would like to delete all files in the listbox like this:

```
try
{
    listBox1.BeginUpdate();

    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            string filename = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();

            if (File.Exists(filename))
            {
                File.Delete(filename);
                listBox1.Items.Remove(filename);
            }
        }
    listBox1.EndUpdate();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    return;
}
```

The above code works, but its only deleting one file every time i click the delete all button. I think I need to add some kind of foreach loop here to iterate through the items but i'm not sure what is the best way to go about it.

Comment: You should not simply catch Exceptions without handling them properly. Here you would get an `OutOfBoundsException` because you are removing elements from a Collection over which you are iterating

Comment: How many files are there in the directory? As per the logic it will delete half of the files in the directory because listview1.Item.Remove will decrease the items.count by 1. So eventually number of iterations will be reduced to the items.count/2.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya The files will always change number. Flat Eric, thanks, I was just typing up a quick test but i will implement the correct exception(IndexOutOfRangeException).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Foreach` statement won't allow you to modify a collection you are iterating through, while `for` will. You just have to be careful with indexes: in your solution after removing the first item (with index=0) the next one become first. Try this approach instead:

```
listBox1.BeginUpdate();

for (int i = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; i >=0; i--)
{
    string filename = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();

    if (File.Exists(filename))
    {
        try
        {
            File.Delete(filename);
            listBox1.Items.Remove(filename);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
}
listBox1.EndUpdate();
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer!

Answer (score 2):

When you remove an item from an array that you are iterating over with the for..next statement, you should consider that every time you delete an element, the array count decrease of one element and every element in the array shifts at a lower index. So, when you delete the element at index 0, the previous element that were at index 1 shifts in position 0, but you have already iterated over the index zero, so you end skipping that element and trying to delete the element that was at index 2 before the removal of the item at index 0.

The solution is simple. Loop in reverse order (from highest element to lowest)

```
for (int i = listBox1.Items.Count-1; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    string filename = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
    if (File.Exists(filename))
    {
        File.Delete(filename);
        listBox1.Items.Remove(filename);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy the contents of the listbox into a string array to prevent errors when remove the items from the listbox in looping.

```
// Copy the contents of the listbox into a string array
string[] filenameList = listBox1.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < filenameList.Length; i++)
    {
        string filename = filenameList[i];
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            File.Delete(filename);
            listBox1.Items.Remove(filename);
        }
    }

}
catch (Exception)
{

}
```